# Does repeated use of the fgetcsv function in this case overwrite the "$line" array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Does it overwrite the $line array? If yes, will renaming the array fix the problem? Furthermore, how can I call data from specific fields in this array through jquery?
I need to make an INTERACTIVE VISUAL to represent all the data being read from these files. How can I go about doing this?
This is the php code:

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n"; 
$f = fopen("LoanStats3a.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$g = fopen("LoanStats3b.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($g)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($g);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
    <?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$h = fopen("LoanStats3c.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($h)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($h);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
    <?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$i = fopen("RejectStatsA.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($i)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($i);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
    <?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$j = fopen("RejectStatsB.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($j)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($j);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: Yes it overwrites the line variable,  yes you can rename it but that may solve your issue or not. Isn't the html output a `visual` representation of the data?  Are you not able to access html from above with javascript?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, however, how can I access it? I want to get data from the same columns in all 3 LoanStats files and the same columns in the RejectStats files. How can I do this?

Comment: Also I dont want it to print the data, I simply want to put it in an array, how can I do this?

Comment: And how do I deal with the intense lag?

Comment: And is it possible to input data from multiple files in the same array, in the same columns?